# Relativsätze für die Verben mit dem Dativ

Tags: sentence-structure, dative, relative-clause

Wie bildet man Relativsätze mit den Verben, die mit dem Dativ funktionieren?

---

Nom: Das ist eben das (dasjenige), was mich interessiert.
Akk: Sie hat das(den, denjenigen) gefunden, was (wen) er verloren hat.

Dat:
Sie wollte dem(jenigen?) nicht glauben, was sie gestern gelesen hat.
Das Rauchen schadet dem, was am wichtigsten ist.

Ist die Dativ-Variante richtig?

Comment: The "wen" in you Akk example is wrong, it has to be "den". In Dat that becomes "dem".

Comment: Danke, warum verwenden man dann "was" in dem Nominative?
Das ist eben das, das mich interessiert. - das ist ganz falsch? vermute ich :)

Comment: Die Dativ-Form von _wer_ ist _wem_, nicht _wen_, und im Neutrum _was_. Es ist also kein Nominativ, ebensowenig das _was_ im zweiten Satz. Abgesehen davon funktioniert _wer_ nur begrenzt als Relativpronomen (in diesem Fall nicht für Personen).

Comment: "das, was", aber "das Buch, das" und "der, der". Frag mich nicht, warum, ich bin nur ein Muttersprachler ;)

Comment: [der, die das](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/RelPron-der-die-das.html) – [wer, was](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-wer-was.html?MenuId=Word4252)

Comment: chirlu, "wen" in meinem Satz korrekt, ich wollte damit sagen:
Sie hat gestern etwas/jn. (Akk.) (zu)gehört. Dem (Dat.) will sie nicht glauben. - in dem Fall ist es für mich nicht klar wem will sie nicht glauben (dem, der das erzählt hat (Person). Oder dem, was sie gehört hat (Mitteilung) )  


Em1, danke für die Antwort, aber ich habe sie ehrlich gesagt nicht (es) verstanden, was du sagen wolltest.

Comment: _Zuhören_ steht mit Dativ.

Comment: Danke, gut aufgepasst. Ich habe es korrigiert.

Comment: @Deni: 'was' als persönliches Fürwort steht nur -> nach Für- und Zahlwörtern mit sächlichem Geschlecht (*das einzige, was ich weiß*) -> nach dem Superlativ eines als Hauptwort gebrauchten Adjektivs (*das Schönste, was ich je gesehen habe*) -> wenn es sich auf den gesamten vorausgehenden Teilsatz bezieht (*Deni stellt sich heute unwissend an, was ihm aber hier übel genommen wird...;-)*

Comment: @Deni: ...und 'wer' oder 'was' kann auch die Rolle des Stellvertreters im übergeordneten Satz übernehmen -> ('*Wer einmal lügt, dem glaubt man nicht...' oder '*Was man schwarz auf weiß besitzt, kann als Beweis verwendet werden...*'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich nehme an, Du meinst mit ...*'Verben, die mit dem Dativ **funktionieren**'*...  Verben, die im Hauptsatz ein Dativobjekt **regieren**. Denn mit dem Relativpronomen kann man auch einen Bezug mit dem Dativobjekt des Nebensatzes herstellen.

- Ich gebe dem (dat.), dem (dat.) ich die Antwort verraten habe, keine Schokolade (-> WEM habe ich die Antwort verraten)

---

Für alle Fälle eine vollständige Auflistung ;-)

---

Bezugswort im Hauptsatz im **Nominativ**:

- Harald ist **der**, *der* (nom.) gesucht wird. (-> *WER* wird gesucht)
- Harald ist **der**, *dem* (dat.) man die Schuld gibt. (-> *WEM* gibt man die Schuld)
- Harald ist **der**, *den* (akk.) ich liebe. (-> *WEN* liebe ich)
- Harald ist **der**, *dessen* (gen.) Frau gestorben ist. (-> *WESSEN* Frau ist gestorben)

---

Bezugswort im Hauptsatz im **Dativ**:

- Ich gebe **dem**, *der* (nom.) die Antwort weiß, eine Schokolade (-> *WER* weiß die Antwort)
- Ich gebe **dem**, *dem* (dat.) ich die Antwort verraten habe, keine Schokolade (-> *WEM* habe ich die Antwort verraten)
- Ich gebe **dem**, *den* (akk.) ich liebe, eine Schokolade (-> *WEN* liebe ich)
- Ich gebe **dem**, *dessen* (gen.) Frau ich liebe, eine Schokolade (-> *WESSEN* Frau liebe ich)

---

Bezugswort im Hauptsatz im **Akkusativ**:

- Ich liebe **den**, *der* (nom.) mir die Antwort verraten hat (-> *WER* hat mir die Antwort verraten)
- Ich liebe **den**, *dem* (dat.) ich die Antwort verraten habe (-> *WEM* habe ich die Antwort verraten)
- Ich liebe **den**, *den* (akk.) ich liebe (-> *WEN* liebe ich)
- Ich liebe **den**, *dessen* (gen.) Frau mir die Antwort verraten hat (-> *WESSEN* Frau hat mir die Antwort verraten)

---

Bezugswort im Hauptsatz im **Genitiv**:

- Ich liebe die Frau **des Mannes**, *der* (nom.) gesucht wird. (-> *WER* wird gesucht)
- Ich liebe die Frau **des Mannes**, *dem* (dat.) man die Schuld gibt. (-> *WEM* gibt man die Schuld)
- Ich liebe die Frau **des Mannes**, *den* (akk.) ich liebe. (-> *WEN* liebe ich)
- Ich liebe die Frau **des Mannes**, *dessen* (gen.) Frau gestorben ist. (-> *WESSEN* Frau ist gestorben)

---

Der Dativ deines Beispielssatzes ist richtig:

Sie wollte dem(jenigen) nicht glauben, *was* sie gestern gelesen hat.

Sie wollte dem(jenigen), *dem* schon die Zeitung keinen Glauben geschenkt hat auch nicht glauben. ;-)

Comment: Viele Dank für so eine ausführliche Antwort!  
Mich würde auch Folgendes interessieren:  

1. Wann benutz man "derjenige/diejenige/dasjenige, " anstatt "der/die/das, ..."  
2. Wann benutzt man "was/wer/wem" als Relativpronomen und wann "der/die/das"?  

Vielleicht muss man dafür eine separate Frage anlegen.

Comment: @Deni: Nicht fragen, erst in Grammatik nachschauen, bitte ...

Comment: @chirlu, dann gibst du bitte mal ein Link, wo das beschrieben ist? ...
Das ist keine gute Antwort "google mal" ...

Comment: @Deni Oh, "Google mal" ist ne sehr gute Antwort. Das hier ist keine "Mach mal für mich die Arbeit"-Seite. Wenn du gegoogelt hast und KEINE zufriedenstellende Antwort hast, DANN frage hier. PS: Anstatt Fragen in Kommentaren zu stellen, eine neue Fragen posten.

Comment: @Em1, warum nimmst du an, das ich nicht gegoogelt habe?
Oder soll ich zu jeder Frage dazu schreiben oder eine Hacke setzen "ja, ich habe gegoogelt"?

Comment: @Deni: Canoo.net ist wirklich gut. http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Rel.html